# Np.sum different for axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I encounter a strange/ interesting behaviour.

I have an array of shape (64,25)

And for the sum of one element of this array (called 'img') we get:

```
print(np.sum(img[::1,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]][14]))
#106.15421 get printed out
```

and for the same element of the np.sum(img, axis=1) we get something different:

```
k = np.sum(img[::1,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]],1)
print(k[14])
#106.15422 get printed out
```

How is this possible, and is there anything I can do?

P.s
I check another way to study this behaviour:

```
print(np.sum(np.delete(img,np.s_[12],1)[14]))
k_d = np.sum(np.delete(img,np.s_[12],1),1)
print(k_d[14])
# Here both times we get 106.15421
```

Comment: The second approach is way better. Having long list of such indices is error prone and hard to read. And the order of first picking the row and than summing or first summing all rows and than picking the one of interest should not play a role for accuracy (other than on a numerical level).

Comment: Well this is also the way I went for, but at another war I calculate a subset of those indeces, but although it the ratio should be 1.0 at one case it's 1.000001 .
So I had to sum the way up and can't use np.delete() for the calculation.

Comment: It takes some patience to read the index list and figure out that you just omitted `12`.  That's rather central to the calculation.  I would have tried `np.sum( img[14,:])-img[14,12]`.  Or if you really want the whole array, `np.sum(img, axis=1)-img[:,12]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed I didn't tried it your way, but mathtematically each version shall have the same result. But I like your way more, due to it's readability.

Answer (score 1):

I checked myself and was able to reconstruct your behavior using float32 type for img:

```
img=np.random.random((64,25)).astype(np.float32)
select=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
Isel=img[:,select]
h=np.sum(Isel[14,...])
print(h)
k = np.sum(Isel,axis=1)
print(k[14],h-k[14])
ks = sum(img[14,select])
print(ks,h-ks)
```

> 10.111376
>
> 10.111374 1.9073486e-06
>
> 10.11137617379427 -3.650784492492676e-07

It does not happen always.
It seems to be a numerical error. If you use float64 it falls of to e-16.
I assume the order or way of addition is different, causing a different round-off.

btw: the generic sum changed to float64 on its own, this is why it is printed out to a greater precision.

Comment: That's what I also have thought that the order may seem to influence somehow. I could use float64, this will at least shift the problem to a negligible dimension.

Comment: I assume you cant use integers

Comment: I calculate ratios, soI expect something between 0 and 1. So integers are off the table.